# Missing WPF styles when using Nuget instead of Reference

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have built and uploaded a nuget package from a ui solution which contains resource dictionaries, custom controls and various helper methods. I have then removed the external dll and reference to it from my main solution and added the nuget package as a dependency.

The custom controls and helper methods work fine. However all the styling is missing as if it can't find the resource dictionaries. However if I directly reference the styles with a dynamic resource they work fine.

If I reset my main solution branch and just replace the direct reference dll with the dll from inside the nuget package it works fine. It also works fine if I make a third solution and use it with a dynamic resource.

My current best guess is that it's no longer able to find inherited styles from the dictionaries but I don't understand how using a nuget package would make any difference.

Edit:

So in the package nuget dll there are a bunch of styling xaml files. They are merged into one large resource dictionary like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="A.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="B.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="C.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

And that resource is in a folder called Styles like so:

```
Solution
  - Project
    - Styles
      - Styles.xaml
```

In nuget I have packaged the output release DLL and all localisation dlls using these lines in the files section:

```
<file src="bin\Release\**\UISolution.dll" target="lib\net40" />
<file src="bin\Release\**\System.Windows.Interactivity.resources.dll" target="lib\net40" />
```

All the dependencies like Prism and Microsoft.Bcl and included under the `.NETFramework4.0` group.

Before when I was using a direct dll reference my main solution had a resource dictionary inside of it that looked like:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary Source="D.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="E.xaml" />
  <ResourceDictionary Source="/UISolution;component/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

There is also this in `MainWindow.xaml` which I think was to make the inherited styles work with the direct dll reference:

```
Application.Current?.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
    new ResourceDictionary
    {
        Source = new Uri("/Styles/Styles.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    });
```

Which was working fine. However now that I have deleted the direct dll reference and installed it by nuget instead this only seems to work if I directly refer to a style using a dynamic resource. All inherited styles seem to have stopped working.

Comment: How did you pack your nuget package with resource dictionaries? And how did you call the resource dictionaries? You may need provide some specific information, otherwise, we just to know the resource dictionaries comes from nuget not work for you, but we could not to know why/how you get this issue. Some reproduce steps should be better.

Comment: I have edited the post to include more detailed information and examples.

Comment: thanks for your update, I have created a test demo, but could not reproduce this issue. I am not sure what I have done is same as you, you can check if my test sample is different from yours:https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfhVkZNrNIF2Pp1Kp5. If it different from yours, If possible, you can share a test sample to me, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. The problem is that the reference to the xaml files is not going to resolve as these are not part of the package. You need to set the properties on your xaml files to "Copy if Newer" and then they will be part of the build and pulled into the nuget package. Once you do this, the method of referencing you used before, "/UISolution;component/Styles/Styles.xaml", will work.